# Object deserialized from XML has default values for some of the fields

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I have small issue with deserializing the object of type `ReaderAttributes`. As you can see, internally it uses `OnOff` class to set some of the fields to be `"ON"` or `"OFF"`

After the object of `ReaderAttributes` deserialized, all the fields except `OnOff` are correctly set from XML file, rest are just set to false. I ran through the debugger, to see how `ReaderAttributes` is being constructed, and noticed that at very end of `Sub New()` it runs through the `Public Sub New()` of the `OnOff` eight times (number of variables of type `OnOff` in `ReaderAttributes`).

```
<Serializable, XmlRoot("ReaderAttributes")>
Public Class ReaderAttributes
    '  <TTY>OFF</TTY>
    Public tty As OnOff
    '  <ECHO>OFF</ECHO>
    Public echo As OnOff
    '  <BAUD>115200</BAUD>
    Public baud As String
    '  <XONXOFF>OFF</XONXOFF>
    Public xonxoff As OnOff
    '  <FIELDSEP>" "</FIELDSEP>
    Public fieldsep As String
    '  <IDREPORT>OFF</IDREPORT>
    Public idreport As OnOff
    '  <NOTAGRPT>OFF</NOTAGRPT>
    Public notagrpt As OnOff
    '  <CHECKSUM>OFF</CHECKSUM>
    Public checksum As OnOff
    '  <IDTRIES>3</IDTRIES>
    Public idtries As Integer
    '  <RDTRIES>3</RDTRIES>
    Public rdtries As Integer
    '  <WRTRIES>3</WRTRIES>
    Public wrtries As Integer
    '  <SELTRIES>1</SELTRIES>
    Public seltries As Integer
    '  <UNSELTRIES>1</UNSELTRIES>
    Public unseltries As Integer
    '  <LOCKTRIES>1</LOCKTRIES>
    Public locktries As Integer
    '  <INITTRIES>1</INITTRIES>
    Public inittries As Integer
    '  <ANTTRIES>1</ANTTRIES>
    Public anttries As Integer
    '  <BRI>ON</BRI>
    Public bri As OnOff
    '  <ANTS>1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0</ANTS>
    Public ants As String
    '  <TAGTYPE>G1</TAGTYPE>
    Public tagtype As String
    '  <EPCIDREPORT>OFF</EPCIDREPORT>
    Public epcidreport As OnOff
    '  <SWTTADDR>18</SWTTADDR>
    Public swttaddr As Integer
    '  <SWTTLEN>1</SWTTLEN>
    Public swttlen As Integer
    '  <POWER>100</POWER>
    Public fieldstrength As String
    Public Sub New()
        tty = New OnOff()
        echo = New OnOff()
        baud = "115200"
        xonxoff = New OnOff()
        fieldsep = " "

        idreport = New OnOff(True)
        idreport.onoff = True

        notagrpt = New OnOff()
        checksum = New OnOff()
        idtries = 3
        rdtries = 3
        wrtries = 3
        seltries = 1
        unseltries = 1
        locktries = 1
        inittries = 1
        anttries = 1
        bri = New OnOff()
        bri.onoff = True
        ants = "1"
        tagtype = "EPCC1G2"
        epcidreport = New OnOff()
        swttaddr = 12
        swttlen = 6
        fieldstrength = "100,100,100,100"
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class OnOff
    Public onoff As Boolean
    Public Sub New()
        onoff = False
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal val As Boolean)
        onoff = val
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        If Me.onoff Then
            Return "ON"
        Else
            Return "OFF"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

And here is the code to that I have used to deserialize.

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(typ)
Dim o As Object 'Object to be deserialized 
Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(str))
      o = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
```

XML (Rather long):

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\" & vbCrLf & \"<ReaderAttributes xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\" & vbCrLf & \"  <tty>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </tty>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <echo>" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </echo>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <baud>115200</baud>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <xonxoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </xonxoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <fieldsep>\" \"</fieldsep>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <idreport>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>true</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </idreport>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <notagrpt>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </notagrpt>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <checksum>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </checksum>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <idtries>3</idtries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <rdtries>3</rdtries>" & vbCrLf & \"  <wrtries>3</wrtries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <seltries>1</seltries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <unseltries>1</unseltries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <locktries>1</locktries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <inittries>1</inittries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <anttries>1</anttries>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <bri>" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>true</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </bri>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <ants>1,4</ants>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <tagtype>EPCC1G2</tagtype>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <epcidreport>\" & vbCrLf & \"    <_onoff>false</_onoff>\" & vbCrLf & \"  </epcidreport>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <swttaddr>12</swttaddr>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <swttlen>6</swttlen>\" & vbCrLf & \"  <fieldstrength>100,100,100,100</fieldstrength>\" & vbCrLf & \"</ReaderAttributes>";
```

Comment: VBA != VB.Net. You're going to have a hard time of things if you don't know what language you're using.

Comment: No Repro; maybe it is the way you are serializing/deserializing, or comparing

Comment: @Plutonix, I forgot to post the code and XML I have used

Comment: still no repro, but my resulting xml string doesnt have all those grody "vbCrLf" elements in it either.

Comment: @Plutonix you mean when you do Obj->XML conversion ?

Comment: where did that xml string come from? why does it look like a long string you are concatenating?  maybe add the code to serialize your object and the actual text output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who might have similar issue. Here the solution.
All it took to fix the bug, is to remove constructors from the `OnOff` class, and within the body of the class, and within the body of the class, set the class data members to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a disconnect between your `Public onoff As Boolean` member variable name and the `<_onoff>` element in your XML.  You could either rename the variable:

```vb
Public _onoff As Boolean
```

Or use an `XmlElement` attribute to tell the serializer the element name:

```vb
<XmlElement(ElementName:="_onoff")>
Public onoff As Boolean
```

Either way should get things to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wrote short program in C# to test out behavior.

http://pastebin.com/HMAgXyvC. It does the same thing

Comment: @newprint Sorry, the C# question was just a curiosity, nothing to do with the problem - and yes, C# will have the same issue if the public variable/property name doesn't match the XML element name.  I'll remove that part.